# Interpreting “all and only” to describe a set

Tags: linear-algebra

V = span[v1, v2, v3]

v1 = [1, 1, 1, 1].T 
v2 = [2, 2, 2, 3].T 
v3 = [1, 1, 2, -1].T

Let W be the subset of V which contains all and only the vectors of V that have the first two components equal to 0(zero).

I can't get W. I don't understand "all and only the vectors of V that have the first two components equal to 0(zero)".

Also, I want to know what is the basis of W.
And, how can I know that W is a subspace of V?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What is $T$?

Comment: T is transpose!

Comment: @quovadisss I returned your question to be something useful.  Please take time to do something similar in the future.  Just writing “can anybody help me with my problem” is not going to cut it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The set $V$ is the set of the vectors of the form$$\alpha[1,1,1,1]^T+\beta[2,2,2,3]^T+\gamma[1,1,2,-1]^T.\tag1$$But $(1)$ is equal to$$[\alpha+2\beta+\gamma,\alpha+2\beta+\gamma,\alpha+2\beta+2\gamma,\alpha+3\beta-\gamma]^T.$$So, $W$ is the set of all vectors of the form $(1)$ such that $\alpha+2\beta+\gamma=0$, since this is the condition tha assures that the two first coordinates of $(1)$ are equal to $0$.

Comment: Thanks, then how can I get a basis of W?

Comment: Since $\alpha+2\beta+\gamma=0\iff\alpha=-2\beta-\gamma$, you take the vectors that you get if $(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)=(-2,1,0)$ and when $(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)=(-1,0,1)$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $W$ is a subspace of $V$, every vector $w\in W$ can be expressed as $\alpha v_1 + \beta v_2 + \gamma v_3$ for some $\alpha,\beta,\gamma \in \mathbb{R}$.

Additionally you know that $w$ is of the form $[0,\  0,\ x, \ y ]^ T$ for some $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$.

So putting all together you have $\alpha + 2\beta + \gamma = 0$ and you can express the subspace $W$ as

$W=\{[0,\ 0\ ,\gamma \ ,\beta-2\gamma]^T$ $\forall\ \beta,\gamma \in \mathbb{R}\}$

Comment: Thanks. It really helped me to understand this issue!

Answer (score 0):

“Contains all” means means every vector from $V$ which begins with two zeros is in $W$.

“Contains only” means every vector in $W$ starts with two zeros. (Only those, nothing more.)

Answer (score 0):

$\bullet$"Only" expresses a necessary condition

" all" expresses a sufficient condition

$\bullet$ This gives :

$W$ is the subset of V such that

(1) if a vector has the 2 first components equal to 0, then this vector belongs to V ( This is the " all" part)

(2) but if it does not have the first 2 components equal to 0, it does not belong to V ( This is he " and only" part).

- Note : not adding the second condition would result in the possibility of having, besides all vectors having null two first components , other vectors not enjoying this property
- Note : when you give a party, you want ***all your friends***... ***and only your friends*** ; without the " only" part, you could have at your party all your friends ***plus*** people you're not particularly pleased to meet.